# How to fetch from Git remotes without tags?

Tags: git

`git fetch --all --no-tags` doesn't do what it says on the tin, and keeps re-fetching tags every time I run it. How do I *actually* fetch from all remotes without fetching tags?

To reproduce:

1. Fork [this repo](https://github.com/cachix/install-nix-action)
2. Clone your fork
3. Add an upstream remote for `git@github.com:cachix/install-nix-action.git`
4. `git fetch --all --no-tags`

What should happen: No tags should be hurt by this transaction.

What actually happens: The remotes clobber each others' tags:

```
❯ git fetch --all --no-tags
Fetching origin
From github.com:example-user/install-nix-action
 - [deleted]                   (none)     -> [omitted]
[…]
Fetching upstream
From github.com:cachix/install-nix-action
 * [new tag]                   [omitted]  -> [omitted]
[…]
```

It even exhibits this behaviour when fetching only the default remote:

```
❯ git fetch --no-tags
From github.com:example-user/install-nix-action
 - [deleted]                   (none)     -> [omitted]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could create an example that didn't involve a repository as large as `nixpkgs`.

Comment: Does `git config --list` show any settings for `prune` or `pruneTags`?

Comment: They are both true.

Comment: @larsks Good point, done.

Comment: It looks like your config is what's driving this behaviour. The intent of `fetch.pruneTags=true` is to always prune tags that don't exist on the remote. The docs aren't clear on how that setting interacts with `--no-tags`, though. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_pruning may be helpful.

Comment: You're right; [fixed](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/merge_requests/444/diffs).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my reading of the [git-fetch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), `--no-tags` only tells git not to fetch any new tags from your remotes. Cleaning up local tags that no longer exist on the remotes you're pulling from is driven by a different setting, namely `fetch.pruneTags`. If the output of `git config --list` shows `fetch.pruneTags=true`, it means you've likely enabled this feature manually at some point. You should remove this setting to go back to the default behaviour of not pruning tags when fetching from remotes.